# Error : Segmentation Fault(core dumped) || Inserting Element into a BST || C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to make a BST from a given array and then traverse it In-Order. There are no compilation errors but at run time the error is **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**. I have been unable to figure out the cause of the error(tried to browse stackoverflow for similar cases). The code is as follows:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    struct TreeNode{
     int data;
     struct TreeNode *right;
     struct TreeNode *left;
    };
    struct TreeNode *newTreeNode(){
     struct TreeNode *node = malloc(sizeof(struct TreeNode));
     if(node){
       node->data = 0;
       node->left = NULL;
       node->right = NULL;
       return node;
     }
     else{
      printf("Memory Error");
     }
    };
    void InorderTraversalRecursive(struct TreeNode *node){
     InorderTraversalRecursive(node->left);
     printf("%d",node->data);
     InorderTraversalRecursive(node->right);
    }

    struct TreeNode *InsertIntoTree(struct TreeNode *node, int data){
     if(node == NULL){
     node = newTreeNode();
     node->data = data;
     node->left = node->right = NULL;
     }
     else{
      if(data > node->data)
        InsertIntoTree(node->right, data);
     else if(data < node->data)
        InsertIntoTree(node->left, data);
     }
    return node;
    }

    struct TreeNode *MakeTreeFromData(int *arr){
     int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
     struct TreeNode *root;
     root = newTreeNode();

     int i;
     for(i=0;i<size;i++){
      InsertIntoTree(root,arr[i]);
     }
     return root;
    }

    void main(){
     int data[] = {4,2,6,1,7,3,5,8};
     struct TreeNode *root;
     root = MakeTreeFromData(data);
     InorderTraversalRecursive(root);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't look on SO for this, but use a debugger.

Comment: sizeof() purpose is not to count an array size. Try: `int size = 8` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious error is in this line

```
int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

where `arr` is not an array but a pointer. This doesn't do at all what you think it is doing. You'd have to pass the size of your array as a parameter to your function.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one powerful tool to know about when coding in C is [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).
Read some tutorials and you won't need to ask this questions.
In my personal experience, I loved the gdb experience with emacs.